# Job for dovecot.service failed server email

Tags: ubuntu, email, dovecot, service, failed

I configure Dovecot and when I want to reset the service it returns the following error:

> Job for dovecot.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dovecot.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I look at the system log and it shows me the following error:

> dovecot[14626]: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf line 22: Unknown setting: service

In the file where I mark the error I have it configured as follows:

```conf
#default_process_limit = 100
#default_client_limit = 1000

# Default VSZ (virtual memory size) limit for service processes. This is mainly
# intended to catch and kill processes that leak memory before they eat up
# everything.
#default_vsz_limit = 256M

# Login user is internally used by login processes. This is the most untrusted
# user in Dovecot system. It shouldn't have access to anything at all.
#default_login_user = dovenull

# Internal user is used by unprivileged processes. It should be separate from
# login user, so that login processes can't disturb other processes.
#default_internal_user = dovecot

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }

service lmtp {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
       mode = 0600
       user = postfix
       group = postfix
    }
  inet_listener imaps {
    #port = 993
    #ssl = yes
  }

 # Number of connections to handle before starting a new process. Typically
  # the only useful values are 0 (unlimited) or 1. 1 is more secure, but 0
  # is faster. <doc/wiki/LoginProcess.txt>
  #service_count = 1

  # Number of processes to always keep waiting for more connections.
  #process_min_avail = 0

  # If you set service_count=0, you probably need to grow this.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    #port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    #port = 995
    #ssl = yes
  }
}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    #mode = 0666
  }

  # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
  #inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    #address =
#port =
  #}
}

service imap {
  # Most of the memory goes to mmap()ing files. You may need to increase this
  # limit if you have huge mailboxes.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit

  # Max. number of IMAP processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

service pop3 {
  # Max. number of POP3 processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Users that have
  # full permissions to this socket are able to get a list of all usernames and
  # get the results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  #
  # The default 0666 mode allows anyone to connect to the socket, but the
  # userdb lookups will succeed only if the userdb returns an "uid" field that

  # matches the caller process's UID. Also if caller's uid or gid matches the
  # socket's uid or gid the lookup succeeds. Anything else causes a failure.
  #
  # To give the caller full permissions to lookup all users, set the mode to
  # something else than 0666 and Dovecot lets the kernel enforce the
  # permissions (e.g. 0777 allows everyone full permissions).
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
   mode = 0666
   user = postfix
   group = postfix
}

unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    #group =
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  #unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  #  mode = 0666
  #}

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  user = dovecot
}

service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  user = vmail
}

service dict {
  # If dict proxy is used, mail processes should have access to its socket.
  # For example: mode=0660, group=vmail and global mail_access_groups=vmail
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user =
    #group =
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have unclosed curly braces in the first defined service `imap-login`

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
```

Comment: Negative, if you look at the code you will see that it is closed, anyway I have tried it and the error continues

Comment: Just count opening and closing braces within service definition. Without closing brace config parser see a `server` directive inside another `server` directive and write that to the log.